# Data inconsistency in similar Cassandra tables

Tags: cassandra

I have 3 similar cassandra tables. Table A1, A2, A3.
All have **same** columns, but **different** partition keys.
Data is inserted in all three tables at same time through sequential inserts using Mapper Library (cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.8.jar)
However, there has been **inconsistency** in few columns.
E.g. Sometimes A1.colX and A2.colX are same but A3.colX is having old value(not updated) and rest all columns in these three tables have exactly same value.
Another time A1.colY and A3.colY may have same value but A2.colY is having old value(not updated) and rest all columns in these three tables have exactly same value.
I am using Mapper Manager to save the input data in Cassandra.

Is it a known problem with mapper manager or something wrong in my approach?

Sample code:

```
public void insertInTables(String inputString){     
        .
        .
        ClassNameA1 classObjectA1=new Gson().fromJson(inputString, ClassNameA1.class);
        ClassNameA2 classObjectA2=new Gson().fromJson(inputString, ClassNameA2.class);
        ClassNameA3 classObjectA3=new Gson().fromJson(inputString, ClassNameA3.class);

        MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session); 
        Mapper<ClassNameA1> mapperA1 = manager.mapper(ClassNameA1.class);
        Mapper<ClassNameA2> mapperA2 = manager.mapper(ClassNameA2.class);
        Mapper<ClassNameA3> mapperA3 = manager.mapper(ClassNameA3.class);

        mapperA1.save(classObjectA1);
        mapperA2.save(classObjectA2);
        mapperA3.save(classObjectA3);
        .
        .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might happen as Cassandra is an eventual consistency store, not strong one. Typical reasons for similar behaviour I've witnessed in my experience are:

- issues with read/write consistency level. If you have RF=3, but write data with CL=ONE, some nodes might fail to replicate your value on write for some reason (like network/hw glitch). Then if you read with CL=QUORUM (or ONE), the quorum may decide to show you the old column value because the new one not propagated to all nodes correctly. So make sure you're writing with CL=ALL/QUORUM and reading with CL=QUORUM.
- issues with hinted hand-off (which is used to protect you from previous issue). Once I've observed a strange behaviour when the first column read was stale/inconsistent (in 1% of all queries), but the second (or third) one shown the correct column value all the time. So try to re-read your inconsistent column multiple times (and think about possible hw/net failures before).
- internal database errors got due to hardware failure or the Cassandra itself.

Most of the issues described above are possible to fix with `nodetool repair`. You can do a full repair and see if this helps.